# The system is running in low-graphics mode in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: dual-boot, graphics, 15.04

I have this issue after updating ubuntu 15, i have tried this [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error) but not got any sucees so please help.

[image]

I am using ubuntu 15.04 with windows 7 in dual boot.

Comment: What GPU do you have?

Comment: i have installed ubuntu desktop

Comment: What is your PC's Graphics Card?

Comment: its is Intel on Toshiba laptop

Comment: @Pilot6 Is Intel graphics card ok for you to answer? =)

Comment: Run `lspci -vv | sed -n '/^.*Graphics/,/^$/p'` and add output to your question. If that doesn't print anything, try replacing 'Graphics' with 'VGA'. EDIT: Probably better to just do `lshw -C display`.